# Sql query for selecting records in between Date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, date-comparison

I am trying to write a query for selecting records based on:

1. They should belong to particular category
2. They should be between Start date and End date.

   I have records like:

   ```
   EventId| EventName| Event_Category| Event_StartDate| Event_EndDate|
      1   |  aaa     |     4         |  2014-06-10    |  2014-06-15  |
      2   |  bbb     |     5         |  2014-06-10    |  2014-06-15  |
      3   |  ccc     |     6         |  2014-06-10    |  2014-07-11  |
      4   |  ddd     |     5         |  2014-06-01    |  2014-07-10  |
      5   |  eee     |     5         |  2014-06-10    |  2014-06-014 |
   ```

   Stored procudure:

   ```
   create proc usp_filterevnts @Categoryid int, @StartDate date, @EndDate date
   as
   begin 
   select * from Events Where Event_Category=@Categoryid  and ( Event_Startdate>@StartDate and Event_Enddate<@EndDate )
   end
   ```

   If i execute the sp as

   ```
     exec usp_filterevnts 5,'2014-06-09','2014-06-16'
   ```

   It should display records of Category 5Th records , whose start date and end date between '2014-06-09' and '2014-06-16 ..ie 2nd record, 5 th record..

   Is my stored procedure correct for this??

Comment: Look up the `BETWEEN` clause.  Is there a particular reason you're doing this in a stored procedure and not just in the query?

Comment: how could i check two dates with BETWEEN clause?? using 'And'??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Events Where Event_Category=@Categoryid and (Event_Startdate between @StartDate and @EndDate) and (Event_Enddate between @StartDate and @EndDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

(depending on table size, and whether the date field has an index...)

Your original syntax, but with >=   and   <= to be inclusive

Between causes a table scan, which won't matter too much if your table is small.

Comment: The operators themselves do *not* cause a table scan. A table scan occurs only if there is no index on the date column or the table is so small that using the index won't help. Actually, both `BETWEEN` and `>= <=` result in the same inclusive range query